# How can I resolve query object error - ValueError: Cannot query "mayur": Must be "User" instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to access my followers in the available module, I can get the number of count such as the number of followers and number of followings but I can't get the list of followers to see my followers. Need suggestions.

My module.py File:

```
from django.db import models

class FollowerFollowing(models.Model):
        user_from = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='rel_from_set')
        user_to = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='rel_to_set')
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)

        class Meta:
            ordering = ('-created',)

        def __str__(self):
            return '{} follows {}'.format(self.user_from, self.user_to)


    User.add_to_class('following', models.ManyToManyField('User', through=FollowerFollowing, related_name='followers', symmetrical=False))
```

My views.py File:

```
def follower(request):
    print(request)
    if request.session['user_id']:
        query = FollowerFollowing.objects.filter(user_from=request.user)
        print(query)
        context = {
            'query': query
            }
        return render(request, 'Instagram_app/following.html', context)
    else:
        pass
    return HttpResponse("No user logged in")
```

follower.html (template)

```
{% extends 'Instagram_app/home.html'%}
{% block content %}
    <h2>following</h2>
    <div id="action-list">
        {% for result in query %}
            <h1>{{ result }}</h1>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Console error is:

```
(value, opts.object_name))
ValueError: Cannot query "mayur": Must be "User" instance.
[20/Jun/2018 11:45:27] "GET /Instagram_app/follower HTTP/1.1" 500 105165
```

Need suggestions to solve this problem. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change this part:
`(user_from=request.user)`
To this:
`(user_from=User.objects.get(username=request.user))`
Your `user_from` must be a `User` model instance, not a simple username.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to change the code to display the following list according to logged in user session

from:

```
query = FollowerFollowing.objects.filter(user_from=request.user)
```

To:

```
query = FollowerFollowing.objects.filter(user_from=request.session['user_id'])
```

because `request.user` gives you the list of single and very first logged in user's following list for all users.